# Vanilla React Page Transitions With Next.js 13's App Router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I tried to build a page transition with React Transition Group for Next.js 13 (using the [App router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app)) and failed.  So in order to understand better what's going on, I first tried to build a minimal transition component without RTG (`main` has `transition: opacity 500ms` here):

```
import { cloneElement, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function Transition({ children }) {
  const [cloned, setCloned] = useState(children);
  const mainRef = useRef();
  useEffect(
    function () {
      mainRef.current.style.opacity = 0;
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        mainRef.current.style.opacity = 1;
        setCloned(cloneElement(children));
      }, 500);
    },
    [children]
  );
  return <main ref={mainRef}>{cloned}</main>;
}
```

What do you think?  As far as I can tell, it's the same mechanism as in RTG.  It works perfectly fine with vanilla React, as far as I have tested it.

Now for Next.js, I declared it as client component, made the effect dependent on `pathname` from `usePathname()` and integrated it into my layout:

```
import Transition from "../components/transition";
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <header>
          <h2>Welcome to Next.js 13!</h2>
          <nav>
        </header>
        <Transition>
          {children}
        </Transition>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

The problem seems to be that in Next.js, the children can change, even though `Transition` defers the update.  So while the CSS transition to transparency and back works fine, the content changes immedeately.  This is exactly what I also witnessed when integrating RTG into Next.js.

What exactly is the nature of `children` in React, is this a static object which needs to be replaced whenever the content changes (as the behaviour in vanilla React suggests), or can the content change independently of its JS object identity?

Any idea what would cause the difference in behaviour and how I could fix it?  Guess I could always let `Transition` hold on to `mainRef.innerHTML` but that seems a little bit ugly.

Comment: You're using next.js, so by definition this is _not_ "vanilla" React.

Comment: Yes, but my `Transition` component is vanilla React as shown above, with vanilla I meant not using RTG, Framer Motion, etc.

Comment: there is no need to re-invent the wheel here

Comment: RTG doesn't work either, I just wanted to exclude any possible bugs or incompatibilities with RTG.

Comment: @fweth If you're using a third part library for transitions (i.e. react-transition-group) instead of plain React state/effect and CSS, that's _also_ not "vanilla". That's very clearly using a third party library. Of course, if the problem is not related to that library, then don't include it in the post, and don't tag the post with it.

Comment: I will remove the tag.  I think it's OK to mention it as reference, since I wanted to go for a similar functionality.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be running into a common issue with Next.js and page transitions. This is likely due to how Next.js pre-renders pages on the server side, causing the content to change instantly when the route changes, even if your opacity transition is still in progress.

A possible solution could be to use Next.js's `useRouter` hook to listen for route changes and control your transition accordingly.

```
import { cloneElement, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Transition({ children }) {
  const [cloned, setCloned] = useState(children);
  const mainRef = useRef();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = () => {
      mainRef.current.style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(() => {
        mainRef.current.style.opacity = 1;
        setCloned(cloneElement(children));
      }, 500);
    };

    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChange);

    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, [children, router]);

  return <main ref={mainRef}>{cloned}</main>;
}
```

This should give you more control over the transition and prevent the content from changing until the transition is complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!  Unfortunately, `router.events` are currently [not supported](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router) in Next.js 13's App router (I'll specify in the question that I want to use App router, but it's Next.js 13's default router).  Also in Next.js 12 I never had a problem with page transitions, so I suspect something changed.